# mvc wrong function called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to web app programming and have been assigned to clean up some legacy code which no one really remembers working on.

Part of this is adding a new function to unsubmit an expense.  I setup the easy function and add a button that should point to it.

When clicked though the button leads to the edit function which there are no mentions of in the unsubmit button.

Here is the code for the unsubmit button.

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Unsubmit",new {id=item.ID}))">UnSubmit</a>
```

And the unsubmit function:

```
public ActionResult Unsubmit(ExpenseItem expenseItem)
    {
        var original = ExpenseItemManager.Get(expenseItem.ID);
        string receiptData = Request.Form["receiptData"];
        expenseItem.Status = 0;

        if (User.ExpenseIdentity().IsAdmin || original.UserId == User.ExpenseIdentity().Id || (expenseItem.CreditCardID.HasValue && expenseItem.CreditCard.UserID == User.ExpenseIdentity().Id))
            return HandleSaveRequests(expenseItem, receiptData);
        else
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(string.Format("{0} does not have access to edit this expense item.", User.Identity.Name));
    }
```

And the declaration for the edit:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult Edit(ExpenseItem expenseItem){...
```

It never enters the unsubmit function, what am I doing wrong and how is it deciding to go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@Url.Action(...)` you are not specifying a Controller and you should be using `expenseId` instead of `id`.

Your `Unsubmit` action is also expecting an `ExpenseItem` object passed instead of the Id. We'll change the signature below as well.

It should look like the below (replace `HomeController` with whatever controller you're in):

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Unsubmit", "HomeController", new { expenseId = item.ID }))">UnSubmit</a>
```

And change your `ActionResult` signature to this:

```
public ActionResult Unsubmit(int expenseId)
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested and its still not working.  Maybe it has something to do with the edit being called from ` <a href="@(Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ID }) + "?page=" + Request.QueryString["page"])" class="button edit">Edit</a>` which doesn't specify a controller and uses the ID to call but somehow has the expenseItem in the function.

Comment: Edit would not have anything to do with this. Could you please update your question with the code you tried (ie: what I have in the answer) and show what isn't working? It should be working 100% right now, I just created a POC to prove that.

Comment: That's what I'm saying that the Edit button works without the controller name.  I put a controller name in the Unsubmit and changed the argument types to match up but it still doesn't work.    `<a href="@(Url.Action("Unsubmit", "ExpensesController", new { expenseId = item.ID }))">UnSubmit</a>`  and `public ActionResult Unsubmit(int expenseID)`  Somehow it still goes to the Edit function.

Comment: Sounds like you might have something going on in your `RouteConfig.cs` file. The fact that the Edit button is working does not make sense. If the edit button is sending over an `Id` (presumably an `int`), there's no possible way it would match the signature that expects an `ExpenseItem` object.

Comment: Okay I will look into that, like I said I'm new to ASP.NET and have no real direction on this project.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, here to help. If you place a breakpoint in that `Edit` `ActionResult` in the `ExpenseController`, it gets hit? If so, what is the value of the `expenseItem` variable? I'm curious.

Comment: That's how I was sure It was hitting the Edit, it never hit the breakpoint in the unsubmit but hit the breakpoint in Edit.  When it comes from the Unsubmit link it has all of the info of an expenseitem.

Answer (score 0):

Your obvious problem is a parameter type mismatch.

Try the below signature:

`public ActionResult Unsubmit(int id)`

Since you are specifiying in your submit that you're submitting a parameter name of id.

Answer (score 0):

One of Url.Action constructors is:

```
Url.Action(string actionName, string controllerName , Parameters)
```

Try this with your controller's name;

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Unsubmit",ControllerName,new {id=item.ID}))">UnSubmit</a>
```

Also you are declaring two different variable names  id and expenseItem, you need use the same variable name either `id` or `expenseItem`(I prefer this one or even a better naming convention) on both